# How to pass a 2D array to a function in Clojure

Tags: multidimensional-array, clojure

I know this is a noob question, but I'm totally new to Clojure.

I have a 2D array, which I've set up as follows:

```
(def my-string-array-2d [ [ "Two" "Arrays" "Of" ]
                          [ "Three" "Strings" "Each"] ])
```

I know I can print the array like this:

```
(doseq [x my-string-array-2d]
  (println x))
```

I've been having a terrible time trying to pass this array to a function. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably there's more to your question, but if you want to pass the array to a function, `(my-function my-string-array-2d)`  Show us what you tried and where you are stuck and I'm sure we can help more.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple, now I feel like an idiot. I tried so many different things, but must have always had unrelated syntax issues that I didn't realize. Thanks for your help.

Comment: also, come join the clojurians slack channel. The #beginner channel is awesome

Comment: Thanks for the invite. This was for a multi-language test bench, but if in the future I decide to learn Clojure for real I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic, but your 2D array is a *vector of vectors* in Clojure parlance, which is similar to an *ArrayList of ArrayLists* in the Java language. Unfortunately in this case the term *array* is overloaded so some people like myself will think your question is about passing some data from Clojure to a function or method that expects `String[][]`. The code example makes it clearer though.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. I honestly thought I was asking about `String[][]` when I asked the question. Sorry to mislead.